# How to make a menu in SQLPlus or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I am making this program that will have a menu that gets the user's input and performs a certain script based on his/her choice. Something along the lines of:

```
Please make a selection:
1: Do script a
2: Do script b
3: Do script c
```

I looked at this link : [How to make SQLPlus or PL/SQL Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850105/how-to-create-a-menu-in-sqlplus-or-pl-sql)

And I was able to get something out of it, BUT it's not fully functional. Because there are certain lines I don't understand. See below.

```
PROMPT  1: Make a sales invoice 
PROMPT  2: Inquire a sales invoice

accept selection PROMPT "Enter option 1-2: "
```

```
set term off
column script new_value v_script  -- What's column script?
select case '&selection.'
       when '1' then '@test.sql'
       when '2' then '@test.sql'
       else '@FinalAssignment.sql'
       end as script  -- What script is this referring to? 
from dual; -- Don't know this

set term on

@&v_script. -- What script is being ran here?
```

I can get the program to run the scripts, BUT the else doesn't really work. If I pick a number outside that range the script will close, instead of reloading itself. Also when a script is ran it closes itself, instead of going back to the main menu. I know I have to run a loop to fix this problem, BUT I don't know how to implement it in this language it.

Any help is appreciated it.
Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1007781 for the "column" thing. That should clear it all up.

Comment: @miguel We should certainly ask sasipriya on this :P

Answer (score 2):

**Ans 1.** Column `script` is the column in the `select` query defined by `as script`, which means `script` is a column alias.

**Ans 2.** `as script` is referring to as a column alias of the `select` stmt. There is only one column in this `select` statement. Example `SELECT column AS col1 FROM table;`. The column [`NEW_VALUE`](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/new_value.html) gets the selected value (which is driven from the `case` stmt, which in this case is the script name `test1.sql`, `test2.sql`, or `FinalAssignment.sql`) and stores it into `v_script`.

**Ans 3.** `dual` table is a special one-row table present by default in all Oracle database installations. More on `dual` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table). You can `select` anything from `dual`, like `select sysdate from dual;` or `select 'ABCDEF' AS col1 from dual;`.

**Ans 4.** The `v_script` column will contain the script name as per your selection from the `case` statement in the `select` query, i.e. from the menu selection (as discussed in Ans 2.). Once that is selected, you may want to run that selected script (Wouldn't you?). Thats what `@&v_script` does. You run a script in SQLPlus using `@script_name`

```
PROMPT  1: Make a sales invoice 
PROMPT  2: Inquire a sales invoice    
accept selection PROMPT "Enter option 1-2: "

set term off
column script new_value v_script  --Q1. What's column script?
select case '&selection.'          --from accept above
       when '1' then '@test1.sql'  --script to run when chosen option 1.
       when '2' then '@test2.sql'  --script to run when chosen option 2.
       else '@FinalAssignment.sql' --this script
       end as script  --Q2. What script is this referring to? 
from dual; --Q3. Don't know this

set term on

@&v_script. --Q4. What script is being ran here?
```

**Caveats**-

1. `FinalAssignment.sql` should be the name of the script itself i.e. the script where the above code is.
2. Line 1,2, and 3 are part of the script. [`PROMPT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12032.htm) is a valid SQL*Plus command and so is [`ACCEPT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12005.htm).